# Is it possible to use Microsoft Project with a less expensive backend than Microsoft Project Server?

Tags: microsoft-project

Our project managers want to use Microsoft Project, but also want the server backend functionality that Microsoft Project Server offers. However, we don't have the budget for Microsoft Project Server. Are there any alternatives for the server functionality?

This question has been asked before, but people were responding with suggestions for different client software. To be more clear, we'd still like to use Microsoft Project as the client, but with a less expensive backend.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sure! Check out [this thread at one of our sister sites called StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278017/alternatives-to-ms-project-server) for a discussion very similar to what you are asking for.

Comment: I saw that thread, but no one really answered the original poster's question. I'm not looking for a methodology or service replacement for Microsoft Project, but simply wondering if it's possible to use the software without Microsoft Project Server.